# What's the use of Intermediate models in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

**Why do we use an intermediate model?**
Can't we just use Many to many relationship without intermediate model?

Comment: It helps to know what your issue or concern is?  Are you asking whether the many-to-many relationship is exactly the same as the intermediate model?  Or that it obviates the intermediate model?  If the latter, please provide an example of a task performed in both fashions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

M2M relationships *require* intermediate tables. You can read more about what M2M relationships are and why they require an intermediate table (referred to as a *junction table* in the article) [here](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php):

Django abstracts this away by automagically creating this [intermediate table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) for you, unless you need to add custom fields on it. If you do, then you can define it by overriding the `through` parameter as shown [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

Here's a quick picture of why the table is required [image]

Answer (score 2):

Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/intermediate-fields-in-django-python/

Let's say you have two models which have a Many-to-Many relationship, like Customer and Product. One customer can buy many products and a product can be bought by many customers.

But you can have some data that doesn't belong to neither of them, but are important to the transaction, like: quantity or date.

Quantity and date are the intermediary data which are stored in intermediary models.

```
from django.db import models 
  
class Item(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 128) 
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 5, decimal_places = 2) 
  
    def __str__(self): 
        return self.name 
  
class Customer(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 128) 
    age = models.IntegerField() 
    items_purchased = models.ManyToManyField(Item, through = 'Purchase') 
  
    def __str__(self): 
        return self.name 
  
class Purchase(models.Model): 
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete = models.CASCADE) 
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete = models.CASCADE) 
    date_purchased = models.DateField() 
    quantity_purchased = models.IntegerField()
```

When you buy a product, you do it through the Purchase model: the client `customer` buys `quantity_purchased` quantity of items `item` in `date_purchased`.

The Purchase model is the Intermediate model.

Django documentation [says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through):

> ...if you want to manually specify the intermediary table, you can use
> the through option to specify the Django model that represents the
> intermediate table that you want to use.

In this case we have this line in the Customer model, which defines the intermediary model in `through = 'Purchase'`

```
items_purchased = models.ManyToManyField(Item, through = 'Purchase')
```

---

**Let's now use the example from the Django [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).**

You have a database of musicians with a Many-to-Many relationship with the bands the belong to: a musician can be part of many bands, and the bands can have many musicians.

What data do you want to keep?

For musicians (person): name and instrument they play
For the bands: name and style.

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    age  =  models.IntegerField() 


class Group(models.Model):
    name   = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    style  = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

But, wouldn't you think that knowing when the person joined the band is important? What model would be the natural place to add a `date_joined` field? It makes no sense to add it to Person or Group, because it's not an intrinsic field for each of them, but it's related to an action: *joining* the band.

So you make a small, but important adjustment. You create an intermediate model that will relate the `Person`, the `Group` with the Membership status (which includes the `date_joined`).

The new version is like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    age  =  models.IntegerField() 


class Group(models.Model):
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    style   = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')


class Membership(models.Model):
    person      = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group       = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
```

The changes are:

1. You added a new class called `Membership` which reflects the membership status.
2. In the Group model you added `members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')`. With this you relate `Person` and `Group` with `Membership`, thanks to `through`.

---

### **Something important to clarify.**

An intermediate model, or in relational database terms, an *associative entity*, are always needed in a Many-to-Many (M2M) relationship.

> A relational database requires the implementation of a base relation
> (or base table) to resolve many-to-many relationships. A base relation
> representing this kind of entity is called, informally, an associative
> table... that can contain references to columns from the same or different database tables within the same database.
>
> An associative (or junction) table maps two or more tables together by
> referencing the primary keys of each data table. In effect, it
> contains a number of foreign keys, each in a many-to-one relationship
> from the junction table to the individual data tables. The PK of the
> associative table is typically composed of the FK columns themselves. ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity))

Django will create the intermediate model, even when you don't explicitly define it with `through`.

> Behind the scenes, Django creates an intermediary join table to
> represent the many-to-many relationship. By default, this table name
> is generated using the name of the many-to-many field and the name of
> the table for the model that contains it.
>
> Django will automatically generate a table to manage many-to-many
> relationships. However, if you want to manually specify the
> intermediary table, you can use the `through` option to specify the
> Django model that represents the intermediate table that you want to
> use.
> The most common use for this option is when you want to associate extra data with a many-to-many relationship.([source](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/django.db.models.ManyToManyField))